# Ubuntu 21.04 WINE Intenet Suddenly Working

Tags: networking, upgrade, wine, internet

I have no Internet in WINE applications since the Ubuntu 21.04 upgrade earlier this year. I’m now running 21.10 and the problem persists and the network connection is working properly within Ubuntu itself. Another post with the same question relates to VPN but I am not using VPN. Any ideas short of reinstalling WINE?

/var/log/syslog at the time a network-enabled WINE application was run shows:

```
Nov  2 10:37:36 WebDev dbus-daemon[2299]: [session uid=1000 pid=2299] Activating via systemd: service name='org.kde.runners.baloo' unit='plasma-baloorunner.service' requested by ':1.212' (uid=1000 pid=24908 comm="/usr/bin/plasmashell " label="unconfined")
Nov  2 10:37:36 WebDev systemd[2278]: Starting KRunner provider for baloo file indexer...
Nov  2 10:37:36 WebDev systemd[2278]: plasma-baloorunner.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Nov  2 10:37:36 WebDev systemd[2278]: plasma-baloorunner.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov  2 10:37:36 WebDev systemd[2278]: Failed to start KRunner provider for baloo file indexer.
Nov  2 10:37:41 WebDev systemd[2278]: Started SendPro.
```

One app in particular gives this error but oddly, if I press the app's Retry button, it sometimes connects which makes no sense. If Ubuntu has a firewall, I am not sure how to access it.

```
login2.pitneybowes.com unexpectedly closed the connection.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

UPDATE: Apparently it's not an issue of Windows application connecting to the Internet as HeidiSQL has no trouble reaching the MySQL database. Somehow SendPro, which was working, now does so only occasionally.

Comment: The upgrade from 20.10 to 21.04 was six months ago. Are you sure you mean 21.04, which is supported for only three more months? Try to run a Wine-using application then check your logs for error messages or troubleshooting information: journalctl and /var/log/syslog.

Comment: Yes, it stopped working in 21.04 but I am running 21.10 now. I’ve not needed it until now.

Comment: @user535733 I added the /var/log/syslog output from the time of running a network-enabled app.

Comment: This problem persists and even completely purging and reinstalling WINE and the Windows applications did not help. Any ideas?